# Browser won't load any pages after 13.10 upgrade

Tags: firefox, 13.10, browser

After my upgrade to 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) Firefox won't load any pages, not even the startup page. I continuously get a "server not found" error. What could it be?

I've looked and no one else has asked about this problem. Also I have removed and installed Firefox from terminal. But after doing so, it won't let me install it again, giving me an error saying

> unable to fetch some archives

Comment: First you should your internet connection (use ping from terminal)
After that, try to open a webpage on you local disk.
Then, try to use anther browser (ex. Google Chrome).
About the error "unable to fetch some archives", I want more detail.

Comment: Web I'm on the terminal and I type in the code to install Firefox, everything goes perfectly and I hit "Y" and enter and it accepts is but after it gets to the last step before completing installation a lot of "fetching http://...etc" pop up and the last one says "unable to fetch some archives"

Comment: I've been having trouble with my internet connection after installing 13.10. Can you access the internet at all (with other programs)?

Comment: @Inkbug No, I will not let me access any programs that require the Internet, they either just won't load, or I get an error.